# Swap texts within html

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change visibilities of two texts, but I don't want a toggle button, just one icon that - when clicked - hides text1 and shows text2, and returns back when clicked again.

I use:

```html
<span onclick="document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML = (this.innerHTML == document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML) ? document.getElementById('text2').innerHTML : document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>and

<div class="content">
  <div id="text1">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>English text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text2">
    <h1>Välkommen</h1>
    <p>Swedish text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Miguel G's answer solves it. However, I still try to figure out how to have the text change in other sections across the entire page.

Comment: "*just one icon that - when clicked - swaps text1 with text2, and returns back when clicked again*" - but that **is** a "toggle button."

Comment: What specific question do  you have? Do you get any errors?

Comment: sorry, I thought a toggle button is like a switch from side to side. I only use a simple icon. But the code doesn't swap the texts, they simple appear both and the icon doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Okay I think I know what you are asking for. You want to be able to click a button or something to switch the inner HTML of these two divs.
You can accomplish that as follows:

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggle()">Click Me!</button
<div class="content" style="display: inline;">
  <div id="text1">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>English text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text2" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Välkommen</h1>
    <p>Swedish text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For your HTML, you can put the onclick property directly into the top div, or you can put it in a separate button. That is up to you. For this one, I added a button on top of the div to allow you to toggle back and forth between the two options. I also put some initial styling in the divs to show whats happening.

```
  const toggle = () => {
  
    let el1 = document.getElementById("text1");
    let el2 = document.getElementById("text2");

    el1.style.display.includes('none') ? el1.style.display = 'inline' : el1.style.display = 'none';
    el2.style.display.includes('none') ? el2.style.display = 'inline' : el2.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

This is the JavaScript function that will swap your divs. Basically now we are just inspecting the style of each div and if it's visible, we make it invisible, and if it's not visible, we make it visible. By using the none property, we assure that they will show up in the same spot.

You can put this function inside a script tag and it should work! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, it's almost what I need but instead of text 1 and 2 swapping places, I want them to replace each other: on load only text1 is visible, on click only text2 is visible and in the same position as text1. The texts are translations and I only want them to switch when clicking the button/icon so that I can avoid full page and image reload.

Comment: ... to be visible individually.

Comment: Got it! I must have misunderstood the question then. Give me one minute and I'll see if I can edit my response for you

Comment: Okay, I edited my response to reflect what you were saying. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Works a charm. Many thanks, Miguel!

Comment: Sadly I can't vote. Newbie.

Comment: Miguel, one more question: I have different sections of text, added the div id's but the text doesn't change. What do I need to do to change the text across the entire page?

Comment: You should be able to "select an answer"
Also, as long as your text is in the divs with the id's of "text1" and "text2" then it should work. If you want a 3rd section, then my js function wouldn't work. We would have to do it a different way. 
If you're changing the div ids, just make sure you change them in the function as well

Comment: Yes, I repeat the divs and ids in another section of the same page but no change there. I don't understand why. To be clear: text1 is English, text2 another language, and I want the texts change across the entire site.

Comment: I guess I also need some function that keeps the language change when moving to another page.

Comment: The document.getElementById("id") function will get the FIRST element with the id of "id". So either you have to put ALL of the text in one language into one div, or you could do it a different way, maybe by using a class and then retrieving all elements with that class name.

Comment: and what would be the best method to keep the language change across the site so a user wouldn't have to click the button on every page?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made a lot of changes in your code, I don't know if this was exactly what you were expecting, but here it is. 
To achieve the desired behavior of showing the content corresponding to each text when the user clicks on its respective element, you will need to make some changes to the HTML code and add JavaScript. 
In this example, I've added code to toggle the display of text corresponding to the clicked button. If the text is visible, it will be hidden and vice versa. In addition, I added a loop to hide all texts except the text corresponding to the current button that was clicked. With these changes, you can click the buttons to show and hide the corresponding content.

```
<style>
  .text {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<!-- add a class to each button -->
<span class="btn" data-target="#text1"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>English</span>
<span class="btn" data-target="#text2"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>Swedish</span>

<div class="content">
  <div id="text1" class="text">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="text2" class="text">
    <h1>Välkommen</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript code -->
<script>
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

  buttons.forEach(button => {
    let isTextVisible = false;
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Get button target
      const target = button.getAttribute('data-target');
      const text = document.querySelector(target);
      // Hides all texts except the current text
      texts.forEach(t => {
        if (t !== text) {
          t.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
      // Shows or hides the text corresponding to the clicked button
      if (isTextVisible) {
        text.style.display = 'none';
        isTextVisible = false;
      } else {
        text.style.display = 'block';
        isTextVisible = true;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, Shirley, not a good idea without JS? I was hoping it could be done simply in HTML.

Comment: @artvanderlay your HTML has a huge JS string in`onclick`, it's not "simply HTML". YOu can put <script> tag just like any other tag.

Comment: ok, but I realise Shirley's solution has two buttons and that's what I try to avoid. I mistakenly called it toggling, but what I try to have is one element that's not changing in appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that instead of swapping the contents of text1 and text2, you want to hide one and make the other visible. I hope the code below helps.

```js
var text1=document.getElementById('text1');
var text2=document.getElementById('text2');

const swap = () => {
  if(text1.classList.contains("hidden")){ //if text1 contains class 'hidden'
    text1.classList.remove("hidden"); //remove hidden class from text1
    text2.classList.add("hidden"); //add hidden class to text2
  }
  else{
    text1.classList.add("hidden"); //add hidden class to text1
    text2.classList.remove("hidden"); //remove hidden class from text2
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="swap()">Switch Text</button>

<div class="content">
  <div id="text1">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>English text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text2" class="hidden">
    <h1>Välkommen</h1>
    <p>Swedish text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this too. Do I place the var text1=document.getElementById('text1');
var text2=document.getElementById('text2'); in <script> and .hidden{
  display:none;
} too?

Comment: You should put **.hidden{ display:none;}** between `<style></style>` tags or in a separate `.css` file. Apart from that, other codes you ask should be put between `<script></script>` tags or in a separate `.js` file. The codes in the code snippet order in my answer are as follows;
**1. HTML code
2. CSS code
3. Javascript Code** Refer this link to see how to add javascript in HTML; **https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-javascript-to-html**

Comment: Thank you! Will this replace all texts on the same page in various sections if I give them the correct id?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by `all texts`. In case of text1 and text2 **yes**, but if you add **text3**, you need to update your javascript code.

Comment: only text1 and text2. I've tried your code but it seems to only swap positions, not visibility. I guess I was unclear in my question, mea culpa! Miguel has edited his code and it works fine, but I haven't managed to work out why the texts don't change in other sections on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<div id="swap-button" style="cursor: pointer;">Click Me</div>

<div class="content">
  <div id="text1">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>English text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text2">
    <h1>Välkommen</h1>
    <p>Swedish text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const swapText = () => {
    const text1Element = document.getElementById('text1');
    const text2Element = document.getElementById('text2');
    const text1 = text1Element.innerHTML;
    text1Element.innerHTML = text2Element.innerHTML;
    text2Element.innerHTML = text1;
  };

  document.getElementById('swap-button').onclick = () => {
    swapText();
  };
</script>
```

Just add your icon instead of

```
<div id="swap-button" style="cursor: pointer;">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: also swapping positions not visibility. Sorry for not asking clearly!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is correct, but i add this answer just in case.

```js
function onloadtext(){
    document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = `<h1>Welcome</h1><p>English text</p>`;
}
 const toggle = () => {
  let el1 = document.getElementById("text1");
  let btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
  if(btn.value == 'Swedish'){
    btn.value = 'English';
    el1.innerHTML = `<h1>Välkommen</h1><p>Swedish text</p>`;
  }else{
    btn.value = 'Swedish';
    el1.innerHTML = `<h1>Welcome</h1><p>English text</p>`;
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="onloadtext()">
 Translate in:<input type="button" id="toggle" onclick="toggle()" value="Swedish">
 <div class="content">
    <div id="text1"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```